# Android draw on canvas

Tags: android, canvas

New to Android development, and I'm having trouble doing a simple drawing to a view using a canvas.

From what I've understood, something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View
{
    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRGB(255,0,0);
    }
}
```

With this as my Activity:

```
public class Prototype1 extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And this for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.dhs2.prototype1.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Should just draw red everywhere, but instead I just get a blank screen.
Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of super.onDraw() and canvas.drawRGB()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you added your custom view in an XML layout file, you should add 2 more constructors:

```
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

This is because you pass some attributes to the view, like `fill_parent`, `wrap_content`, so the constructor `public DrawView(Context context)` won't be called.

This would work however, if you won't declare your custom view in the XML layout file, but setting it directly from the `onCreate()` like this:

```
setContentView(new DrawView(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for stepping in with the correct answer.  One other thing to note with this is that when I tried to run the code from the original question the debugger "broke" and the stack trace indicated that the activity threw an exception.  The question said that "a black screen displayed" indicating that the program successfully ran without exceptions.  Beyond just supplying the answer to the question, it should be noted that paying attention to the debugger and logcat, and noting that the app is in the process of crashing is very important.